# Divide the rational expressions below and simplify as much as possible:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is :

> $$\frac{x^2 + 8}{2x^2 + x - 3}\div\frac{x + 2}{x - 1}$$

the answer I get is

$$\frac{x^2 + 8}{(2x + 3)(x + 2)}$$

but a further factor of $x+2$ is factored out somehow from the $x^2+8$.

I'm having doubts about this. please help, thanks

ANSWER GIVEN BY PROF:

> $$\frac{(x+2)\left(x^{2}-2 x+4\right)}{(x-1)(2 x+3)} \cdot \frac{x-1}{x+2}=\frac{x^{2}-2 x+4}{2 x+3}$$

Comment: $x^2+8$ doesn't factor over the reals

Comment: my math teacher factored it , I dont know how

Comment: Could it be $x^3+8=(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$?

Comment: I will post the answer given by my teacher, I have no idea how she got it.

Comment: I don't think so Ross, check out the answer given by prof in imgur link

Comment: @jcx3x Ross is 100% correct, in the sense that its what your prof did: please expand the top of your prof's answer. BTW I copied it into formatted mathJax

Comment: I'm just not seeing it, I dont understand how we can factor the (x^2+8) , I just don't see it...

Comment: @jcx3x no, you can't, either your question should have been $x^3+8$ or your prof made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer given by the prof $(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)=x^3+8$.  It seems the problem statement has the wrong exponent on the $x$ at the start.  Your answer is correct for the problem as given.